# Git shows wrong push author but correct commit author

Tags: git, github

My dev team is banging our heads against the wall trying to figure this out.  Two of my team members show activity under our old CTO/Developer when pushing, but correct author on the commit level.

Example (censored)

```
OLD_CTO_USERNAME pushed to integration at charitybuzz/charitybuzz
OLD_CTO_FULLNAME
 CORRECT_COMMIT_AUTHOR 3d5e7d3 getting rid of duplicate slim gem
```

Comment: Um, git doesn't natively track who pushes what, it only tracks commits. Are you referring to a log on GitHub or something? If that's the case, GitHub actually uses your GitHub account's username and email address for recording commits, which may differ from what you have setup on your local machine. So, for example, when you commit or merge pull requests through GitHub's web interface instead of git's command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the mystery of the rouge pusher.    Turns out our old CTO had actually added those keys to his own account, instead of letting our new devs add them to their own.   Not really sure why he did so, but this is the reason.

We couldn't get in touch with him and ask him to remove the keys so we created a new key JUST for github, added a ssh config that set key by domain.

```
Host github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/just_for_github.key
Host *
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```